# Is it possible to limit the rows per value in a WHERE col IN(...) statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id IN (val_1, val_2, ..., val_n) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 15;
```

As I have explored in an earlier post there is no way to make this use an index for the ordering.

But is there any way to limit the amount of rows MySql stores in a temporary table for each value in the `IN(...)` statement?

In other words, tell the db to fetch x rows where user_id = value_1, then x rows from where user_id = value_2, and so on.

I need to limit this as I don't want the db to do a sort on too many rows and I just need the most recent entries of each user.

I have already solved this by adding `AND WHERE count <= m` and I make sure that the most recent m entries of the user have a count <= m but this is slowing down my system when entries are made as I have to increase `count` on m-1 entries and set count to > m on the oldest one.

Using `FULL JOIN` is not an option. It does what I want but the execution of all the joins is very slow (I would need 50+ joins).

Answer (score 0):

One method is brute force:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE user_id = val_1
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 15
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE user_id = val_2
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 15
UNION ALL
. . .
```

Although this may seem "brute force", it can take advantage of an index on `(user_id, timestamp)`, so it might be efficient.

If you want up to "n" rows for each value, then variables can help:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (@rn := if(@u = user_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@u := user_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM table t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0, @u := -1) params
      ORDER BY user_id, timestamp DESC
     ) t
WHERE rn <= 15
ORDER BY user_id, timestamp DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the most recent entry per user then you are looking at a GROUPWISE MAXIMUM problem. See the solutions in the MySQL manual [tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)